# alternative to "netstat -s"

Tags: linux, netstat, iproute

[`netstat -s`](http://mdoc.su/f/netstat.1) prints out a lot of very detailed protocol statistics like number of TCP reset messages received or number of ICMP "echo request" messages sent or number of packets dropped because of a missing route.

When in Linux `netstat` is considered deprecated at nowadays, then is there an alternative?

Statistics provided by `ss -s` are superficial compared to the ones provided by `netstat`.

Comment: tcpdump seems to fill the same need

Comment: `netstat` is deprecated. Use `ss`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey `tcpdump` allows one to capture live traffic, but does not store statistics in a way `netstat -s` shows.

Comment: Specifying the platform would probably be useful. You may want to examine `sysctl` output or the contents of various `/proc/net/*` nodes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`netstat` has indeed been deprecated by many distributions, though it's really much of the "net-tools" package (including `ifconfig`, `route` and `arp`) that has been deprecated in favour of the "iproute2" package. [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) has evolved [along with the latest Linux networking features](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/), and the traditional utilities have not.

The iproute2 equivalent that you want is the little known `nstat`, this provides the `netstat -s` counters, albeit in a slightly different form:

- raw counter names from `/proc` are used, each prefixed with its class ("Udp", "Tcp", "TcpExt" etc)
- netstat's long (and possibly localised) descriptions are not available
- zero-value counters omitted by default
- using consistent columnar output with the name and value in the first and second columns
- third column shows the average over a configurable time window if you have started a background nstat (`-d` daemon mode), or 0.0 if not

  e.g. `nstat` prints "UdpInDatagrams NNN" not "Udp: InDatagrams", and not the verbose netstat version of "Udp: NNN packets received".

`nstat` also assumes you want incremental rather than absolute numbers, so the closest equivalent to `netstat -s` is `/sbin/nstat -asz` where the options are `-a` use absolute counters, `-s` don't keep history file, `-z` don't omit zero-value counters.

`ss` takes over the "socket" parts of `netstat`, but not its complete function as you have found out. (`ss` is actually better than `netstat` in many cases, two specific ones are the ability to use filter expressions and the optional capability to use the `tcp_diag` and `inet_diag` Linux kernel modules to access kernel socket data more directly than via `/proc`.)

Should you need to confirm the mapping for descriptive names, the net-tools source is the definitive reference: http://sourcecodebrowser.com/net-tools/1.60/statistics_8c_source.html

Doug Vitale provides a [useful guide](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/) for finding the iproute2 equivalents of the older commands (it is unmaintained and slightly incomplete, it omits any reference to `nstat` which has been part of the iproute2 package [since at least 2004](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2/) kernel 2.6.x time).

net-tools [lives on](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/) however, and you should be able to find a package for your distribution (or compile it yourself).

Answer (score 59):

Netstat is considered deprecated at nowadays and other programs included in the net-tools like  arp, ifconfig, iptunnel, nameif, `netstat`, and route.

The functionality provided by several of these utilities has been reproduced and improved in the new **iproute2** suite, primarily by using its new `ip` command.

Examples for deprecated commands and their replacements:

- `arp`  → `ip n` (`ip neighbor`)
- `ifconfig` → `ip a` (`ip addr`), `ip link`, `ip -s` (`ip -stats`)
- `iptunnel` → `ip tunnel`
- `iwconfig` → `iw`
- `nameif`   → `ip link`, `ifrename`
- **`netstat`**  → `ss`, `ip route` (for `netstat -r`), `ip -s link`
  (for `netstat -i`), `ip maddr` (for `netstat -g`)

The `netstat` command reads various `/proc` files to gather information. 
However, this approach falls weak when there are lots of connections to display. 
This makes it slower. 
The `ss` command gets its information directly from kernel space. 
The options used with the `ss` commands are very similar to `netstat`,
making it an easy replacement.

Statistics provided by `ss` are **superficial**
but it is considered **the better alternative** to `netstat`.
<sup>[Citation needed]</sup>

#### Examples

```bash
ss | less  # get all connections
ss -t      # get TCP connections not in listen mode
ss -u      # get UDP connections not in listen mode
ss -x      # get Unix domain socket connections
ss -at     # get all TCP connections (both listening and non-listening)
ss -au     # get all UDP connections
ss -tn     # TCP without service name resolution
ss -ltn    # listening TCP without service name resolution
ss -ltp    # listening TCP with PID and name
ss -s      # prints statistics
ss -tn -o  # TCP connections, show keepalive timer
ss -lt4    # IPv4 (TCP) connections
```

See note in the [netstat(8) manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html):

> **NOTES**
>
>   This program is mostly obsolete. 
>   Replacement for
>   **`netstat`**
>   is
>   **`ss`**
>   . 
>   Replacement for
>   **`netstat -r`**
>   is
>   **`ip route`**
>   . 
>   Replacement for
>   **`netstat -i`**
>   is
>   **`ip -s link`**
>   . 
>   Replacement for
>   **`netstat -g`**
>   is
>   **`ip maddr`**
>   .

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP points out correctly that `ss -s` *does not provide* data that `netstat -s` provides. This also contains misinformation: `/proc` *is* the kernel interface for this and that's exactly how `ss` obtains much of the data: `strace -e trace=file,read /sbin/ss -s` .

Comment: The OP said not the entirely "ss are superficial", but "`ss -s` are superficial compared to the ones provided by netstat" (means comparing to `netstat -s`). And it's really the truth: e.g., from ss -s you can know nothing about TCP Retransmissions.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check the contents of `/proc/net/netstat`:

```
TcpExt: SyncookiesSent SyncookiesRecv SyncookiesFailed EmbryonicRsts PruneCalled RcvPruned OfoPruned OutOfWindowIcmps LockDroppedIcmps ArpFilter TW TWRecycled TWKilled PAWSPassive PAWSActive PAWSEstab DelayedACKs DelayedACKLocked DelayedACKLost ListenOverflows ListenDrops TCPPrequeued TCPDirectCopyFromBacklog TCPDirectCopyFromPrequeue TCPPrequeueDropped TCPHPHits TCPHPHitsToUser TCPPureAcks TCPHPAcks TCPRenoRecovery TCPSackRecovery TCPSACKReneging TCPFACKReorder TCPSACKReorder TCPRenoReorder TCPTSReorder TCPFullUndo TCPPartialUndo TCPDSACKUndo TCPLossUndo TCPLostRetransmit TCPRenoFailures TCPSackFailures TCPLossFailures TCPFastRetrans TCPForwardRetrans TCPSlowStartRetrans TCPTimeouts TCPLossProbes TCPLossProbeRecovery TCPRenoRecoveryFail TCPSackRecoveryFail TCPSchedulerFailed TCPRcvCollapsed TCPDSACKOldSent TCPDSACKOfoSent TCPDSACKRecv TCPDSACKOfoRecv TCPAbortOnData TCPAbortOnClose TCPAbortOnMemory TCPAbortOnTimeout TCPAbortOnLinger TCPAbortFailed TCPMemoryPressures TCPSACKDiscard TCPDSACKIgnoredOld TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo TCPSpuriousRTOs TCPMD5NotFound TCPMD5Unexpected TCPSackShifted TCPSackMerged TCPSackShiftFallback TCPBacklogDrop TCPMinTTLDrop TCPDeferAcceptDrop IPReversePathFilter TCPTimeWaitOverflow TCPReqQFullDoCookies TCPReqQFullDrop TCPRetransFail TCPRcvCoalesce TCPOFOQueue TCPOFODrop TCPOFOMerge TCPChallengeACK TCPSYNChallenge TCPFastOpenActive TCPFastOpenPassive TCPFastOpenPassiveFail TCPFastOpenListenOverflow TCPFastOpenCookieReqd TCPSpuriousRtxHostQueues BusyPollRxPackets
TcpExt: 0 0 3310 41566 0 0 0 8 0 0 6402271 0 0 0 0 55 4280514 134510 38423 0 611 15354484 20413302 794718685 0 14094957 6423168 25905597 17269587 4 23681 29 50 20 0 25 43 25 19211 1800 131 0 93 93 25430 4864 18099 1199566 2300620 1280201 0 279 0 0 38507 607 2359841 19 98943 1769 0 5993 0 0 0 3 65 1310588 380 0 0 0 0 613504 190 0 12056356 0 0 0 0 3 735740 43633 0 606 3933 193 0 24 0 0 0 14 0
IpExt: InNoRoutes InTruncatedPkts InMcastPkts OutMcastPkts InBcastPkts OutBcastPkts InOctets OutOctets InMcastOctets OutMcastOctets InBcastOctets OutBcastOctets InCsumErrors InNoECTPkts InECT1Pkts InECT0Pkts InCEPkts
IpExt: 0 0 50492 0 18482301 0 68850196397 26546692767 3029352 0 2305454225 0 0 457718114 36 19480 2472
```

Not the most friendly format, but you get the idea.

Not sure it actually contains the specific items you're looking for, but they may be available elsewhere in `/proc/net`.

Comment: here's a (single long line) script to format the output: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)title[i] = $i; getline; print title[1]; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf " %s: %s\n", title[i], $i }' /proc/net/netstat`

Comment: `/proc/net/snmp` contains *most* of the data and `/proc/net/netstat` contains the rest. Sadly you'll need to read [net-tools `statistics.c` source](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/net-tools/1.60/statistics_8c_source.html) to determine all the name mappings, though most are quite obvious.