# Alternative to netstat -an

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and the `netstat -an` command doesn't exist.  I can install it `sudo apt install net-tools` but wanted to know what the modern day command is for this command.

The `nestat -an` command lists all of the ports that are being used on the system (TCP, IP, Unix Domain Sockets).  The `-n` says to display the port as a number.

I did a search and found:
[alternative to "netstat -s"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258711/alternative-to-netstat-s) -which was good, but did not include an answer for `netatat -a`.

Another answer suggested `ss` but didn't provide any reason.  This might be the answer.

Comment: I thought that `ss` has exactly the same options as `netstat`. While the output of `ss -na` is not formatted the same as `netstat -an`, can you check if the content corresponds to your expectations?